# App not downloading the most current plist when using AFNetworking. Caching?

Tags: ios, caching, afnetworking

I have a version checker inside my app and I have the current version number stored in a plist on the server. For some reason it keeps returning the old value when I have confirmed that it is 1.21 when it keeps saying 1.2. I believe it's some sort of caching as my browsers do the same thing.

How do I prevent this from happening? I set the cachePolicy to `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData`, but it's still returning 1.2 when it's 1.21

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://somewebsite.com/iosapp/CurrentVersion.plist"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData;

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[AFPropertyListRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/xml"]];
AFPropertyListRequestOperation *operation = [AFPropertyListRequestOperation propertyListRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id propertyList) {
    NSString *currentVersion = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:propertyList] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Current Version %@", currentVersion);
    NSString *deviceVersion = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey: @"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
    if (![currentVersion isEqualToString:deviceVersion]) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Update Available" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"App %@ is available. Please update.", currentVersion] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Later" otherButtonTitles:@"Update", nil];
        [alert show];
    }


    [self finalCheck];
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id propertyList) {
    [self finalCheck];
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

The [implementation of AFPropertyListRequestOperation](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFPropertyListRequestOperation.m) doesn't do anything related to caching.  Here are a few options:

1. A proxy or intermediary could be caching it.  Try `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData` instead.
2. The response to `[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey: @"CFBundleShortVersionString"]` might not be what you're expecting (I notice you're not logging it.)

I'd also like to recommend you check out two libraries:

- [Harpy](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Harpy), an easy-to-add, low maintenance library that checks the newest version using the iTunes API, and nags your users at an interval you specify.
- [Ground Control](https://github.com/mattt/GroundControl), a simple category on NSUserDefaults that asynchronously downloads, reads, and saves a remote plist file.

The first will circumvent your need to write any of this code.  The second will make it easier if you need a little more control / customization.